# Vundle/vim can't see changes in .vimrc

Tags: vimrc, macvim, plugin-vundle

I'm enforcing some strange behaviour of Vundle plugin. Basically, from time to time, i'm not able to install new plugins using `:PluginInstall` because Vundle can't see the new `Plugin` entries in my `.vimrc` file. The results displayed by `:PluginInstall` contains few plugins from .vimrc but not the recently added ones. I was able to fix that temporary by closing MacVim, opening a terminal vim and running `PluginInstall` there but it stopped working and now i'm completely not able to install new plugins anywhere.

It behaves like the `.vimrc` file has been cached somewhere but i can't find such cached one and there is no any `.vimrc.swp` file present so i feel quite lost.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @mbajur can you post a link to your vimrc.

Comment: sure, here you go: https://gist.github.com/mbajur/ab5fabf80cd7e000b230

Comment: What you describe sounds a bit to me like you don't source your .vimrc. Try to open vim again, run `:edit $MYVIMRC`, make your changes and save them with `:w`, then source the .vimrc with `:source %`, and then run `:PluginInstall`. Does the error persist?

Comment: yes, that helped :) However, i'm not sure if that's just working temporary or will occur again in a day or two. Anyway - is that normal? Should i always source my vimrc before `:PluginInstall` ? (post your comment as an answer and i'm gonna accept it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim parses your `.vimrc` once when it is started. Whenever you change something in it (in your case add a new plugin), vim needs to be told manually that something changed so that the `.vimrc` gets parsed again. You do that by running `:source $MYVIMRC`. I often shorten that to `:so %` when my `.vimrc` is opened (`%` gets expanded to current file name).

After sourcing your `.vimrc`, all saved changes are processed and should take effect, so you can run your `:PluginInstall` command.

In general, your `:PluginInstall` command will only work if the `.vimrc` was sourced. What you can do to save you doing this small step manually over and over again is to [automate it](http://www.bestofvim.com/tip/auto-reload-your-vimrc/):

```
augroup reload_vimrc " {
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost $MYVIMRC source $MYVIMRC
augroup END " }
```

That way, whenever you save changes to your `.vimrc`, it gets sourced automatically.

Comment: great answer! I was sure that `PluginInstall` loads `.vimrc` on it's own each time i'm running it. Thank you for clarification.